# Why do i get hexadecimal numbers in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was making a three dimensional array in c++ and I get hexadecimal numbers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arer[2][3][3] = {{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}, {{10,11,12}, {13,14,15} ,{16,17,18}}};
    for(int x = 0;x <= 18;x++){
        cout << arer[x] << "     ";
    }

return 0;           
}
```

I used to get an output like

```
0xbebd5ea4
```

and more like these

Comment: Stop thinking whatever it is you're thinking. Don't go out of bounds; your bounds are 2, 3 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

This the right way to print a 3D array:

```
int main(){
    int arer[2][3][3] = {{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}, {{10,11,12}, {13,14,15} ,{16,17,18}}};
    for(int i = 0;i < 2;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++){
            for(int k = 0;k < 3;k++){
                std::cout << arer[i][j][k] << "     ";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What you are doing is printing the addresses of some memory.

Answer (score 2):

`arer` is a 3-dimensional array (an array of 2-dimensional arrays).  `arer[x]` is a 3x3 array of int.   An array, when passed to any function as an argument (which includes stream's `operator<<()`) is converted to a pointer (to the first element).      If passing a 3x3 array, a pointer to an array of 3 elements is passed.

Since one variant of `ostream`s `operator<<()` accepts a `void *`, most pointers will be implicitly converted to `void *` and passed to that version.   That is what is happening here.   A `void *` represents an address in memory.  By convention, addresses are often printed in a hexadecimal form.

Also, in your example, `arer[x]` is only valid if x is `0` or `1` (valid values of the first index).   Other values (up to `18` inclusive in your loop) are not valid elements of `arer` - so accessing them gives undefined behaviour.